# gulp-compass error "You need to have Ruby and Compass installed and in your system PATH"

Tags: windows, sass, gulp, compass

I'm using [gulp-compass](https://www.npmjs.org/package/gulp-compass) to compile my `scss` to `css` using gulp task. I'm running on Windows 7.
My Gulp task:

```
gulp.task('styles', function() {
      gulp.src('./sass/design.scss')
    .pipe(compass({
      config_file: './config.rb',
      css: 'stylesheets',
      sass: 'sass',
      require: ['susy', 'breakpoint']
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dest/css'));
});
```

I get the following error message:

```
Error: You need to have Ruby and Compass installed and in your system PATH for this task to work.
```

I have Ruby and Compass installed and in my system PATH so I can't see what's the problem.
I tried re-installing both Ruby and Compass and it didn't help either.

When I tried to use the same task on a Mac system it worked fine.

Replacing the `gulp-compass` plugin to [gulp-ruby-sass](https://www.npmjs.org/package/gulp-ruby-sass) is not an option due to a bug they have which block me from using certain sass features I need to use.

Comment: Did you install compass through Gem or Npm? Cause I remember that months ago I had an issue with the Npm installation giving your same error. I fixed it installing compass with gem.

Comment: I installed compass with gem

Comment: What have you typed to install compass?

Comment: gem install compass
and after that i also tried:
gem install compass --pre

I can write "compass watch" and it works fine so it's strange.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have Windows 7 environment. I think you must add the following path to your system PATH.

```
C:\Ruby193\bin
```

- http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_installation_windows.htm
- http://rubyonwindowsguides.github.io/book/ch01-01.html

Comment: As i mentioned, I already have Ruby on the system PATH. The only thing I can think of is a bug in gulp-compass plugin.

Comment: I try my project as html5-template-engine 
https://github.com/appleboy/html5-template-engine It is working on Windows XP and Ruby 1.9.3.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue and resolved it by removing double quotes from my system path.
I had an entry for:

```
c:\"Program Files"\Perforce;
```

I changed it to:

```
c:\Program Files\Perforce;
```

The script apparently can't handle double quotes.

You can also get around this by explicitly adding the ruby folder to the "External Web Tools" locations but fixing the path is a better solution.